# Difference between from collections import Container and from collections.abc import Container

Tags: python-3.x, abc

We can import `Container` in two ways:

1. `from collections import Container`
2. `from collections.abc import Container`

`help` function for both `Container` returns the same documentation.

`help(collections.Container)`:

```
Help on class Container in module collections.abc:

class Container(builtins.object)
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __contains__(self, x)
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Class methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __subclasshook__(C) from abc.ABCMeta
 |      Abstract classes can override this to customize issubclass().
 |      
 |      This is invoked early on by abc.ABCMeta.__subclasscheck__().
 |      It should return True, False or NotImplemented.  If it returns
 |      NotImplemented, the normal algorithm is used.  Otherwise, it
 |      overrides the normal algorithm (and the outcome is cached).
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data and other attributes defined here:
 |  
 |  __abstractmethods__ = frozenset({'__contains__'})
```

`help(collections.abc.Container)`:

```
Help on class Container in module collections.abc:

class Container(builtins.object)
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __contains__(self, x)
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Class methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __subclasshook__(C) from abc.ABCMeta
 |      Abstract classes can override this to customize issubclass().
 |      
 |      This is invoked early on by abc.ABCMeta.__subclasscheck__().
 |      It should return True, False or NotImplemented.  If it returns
 |      NotImplemented, the normal algorithm is used.  Otherwise, it
 |      overrides the normal algorithm (and the outcome is cached).
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data and other attributes defined here:
 |  
 |  __abstractmethods__ = frozenset({'__contains__'})
```

What is the difference between these two imports? Why are we allowed to do both?

**Update**

Got deprecation warning while importing `Container` from `collections` (`Python 3.7.3`).

From `Python 3.8` it cannot be imported directly from `collections`.

```
>>> from collections import Container
```

> **main**:1: DeprecationWarning: Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated, and in
>   3.8 it will stop working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Python 3 documentation for the `collections` module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html):

> *Changed in version 3.3:* Moved
>   [Collections Abstract Base Classes](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes)
>   to the [`collections.abc`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.abc.html#module-collections.abc)
>   module. For backwards compatibility, they continue to be visible
>   in this module through Python 3.7.
>   Subsequently, they will be removed entirely.

These "Collections Abstract Base Classes" currently include
`AsyncGenerator`, `AsyncIterable`, `AsyncIterator`, `Awaitable`,
`Bytestring`, `Callable`, `Collection`, `Container`, `Coroutine`,
`Generator`, `Hashable`, `ItemsView`, `Iterable`, `Iterator`, `KeysView`,
`Mapping`, `MappingView`, `MutableMapping`, `MutableSequence`,
`MutableSet`, `Reversible`, `Sequence`, `Set`, `Sized`, `ValuesView`.

In Python 3.8 importing them from `collections` will stop working.
In Python 3.3 to 3.7, they can be imported from `collections` or
from `collections.abc` (it gives the exact same classes).
In Python 3.7, importing them from `collections` prints a
deprecation warning, since Python 3.8 is getting near.

In Python 2 they can only be imported from 'collections',
not from 'collections.abc'.

One simple way to deal with this is a try/except block:

```
try:  # works in Python >= 3.3
    from collections.abc import Sequence
except ImportError:  # Python 2, Python <= 3.2
    from collections import Sequence
```

Another commonly used workaround is to conditionally
import from `collections` or `collections.abc` depending
on the Python version being used.

For instance, have a `PY2` boolean and do:

```
if PY2:
    from collections import Sequence
else:
    from collections.abc import Sequence
```

This boolean is usually obtained either using `six`:

```
from six import PY2
```

or using `sys.version_info`:

```
import sys
PY2 = int(sys.version_info[0]) == 2
```

If we anticipate that Python 4 is likely to work like Python 3.3+
in this respect, special-casing Python 2 seems more future-proof
than special-casing Python 3, which could be done as follows:

```
if PY3:
    from collections.abc import Sequence
else:
    from collections import Sequence
```

where the `PY3` boolean can be obtained either using `six`:

```
from six import PY3
```

or using `sys.version_info`:

```
import sys
PY3 = int(sys.version_info[0]) == 3
```

The try/except approach above seems even more robust though
(e.g. it works with Python 3.2 with no extra effort).