# Cannot import 'collections.abc' when using windows subsystem for linux

Tags: python, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using windows subsystem for linux (specifically Ubuntu for Windows) to run some python code. When I try to run the following: 'import collections.abc', I get the following error: 'ImportError: No module named abc'.

I can import 'collections', but if I try: 'collections.abc', I get the following error: 'AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'abc''.

Furthermore, I tried importing the module in command prompt without using Ubuntu for Windows, and it imports successfully.

The 'collections' module should be included in python by default, so I'm not sure why it's giving me this error.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? `collections.abc` is introduced in version 3.3. Does `python -V` in a command prompt return the same version number as `python -V` in the Ubuntu sub system?

Comment: You can also `import sys`, then `print(sys.version_info)` to see what version of Python is being run.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Python 3 documentation for the `collections` module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html):

> *Changed in version 3.3:* Moved
>   [Collections Abstract Base Classes](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes)
>   to the [`collections.abc`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.abc.html#module-collections.abc)
>   module. For backwards compatibility, they continue to be visible
>   in this module through Python 3.7.
>   Subsequently, they will be removed entirely.

So any content of `collections.abc` that already exists in
Python <= 3.2, including Python 2, is found in `collections`
directly.

To support all versions of Python, use a try/except block:

```
try:  # works in Python >= 3.3
    import collections.abc as collections_abc
except ImportError:  # Python <= 3.2 including Python 2
    import collections as collections_abc
```

Then use e.g. `collections_abc.Sequence` instead of
`collections.abc.Sequence` in Python >= 3.3 and
`collections.Sequence` in Python <= 3.2.

See a longer discussion in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56505951).

Answer (score 0):

For backward compatible code use module six (doc: https://six.readthedocs.io/index.html?highlight=abc#module-six.moves)

For example:

```
from six.moves.collections_abc import Iterable

isinstance([1, 2, 3], Iterable) # -> True
isinstance({1, 2, 3}, Iterable) # -> True
```