# `from typing` vs. `from collections.abc` for standard primitive type annotation?

Tags: python, python-typing, standard-library

I'm looking at the [standard library documentation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.12/Lib/typing.py), and I see that `from typing import Sequence` is just calling `collections.abc` under the hood.

Now originally, there was a deprecation warning/error and migration from the `collections` package to `collections.abc` for some abstract classes. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55882715/difference-between-from-collections-import-container-and-from-collections-abc-im). However, now that the abstractions have settled in a new location, is it fine to use either? I see `from collections.abc import [etc]` in the codebase, and I wonder if it would be more practical to just import from `typing` when trying to do type annotations?

Cython source code:
`Sequence = _alias(collections.abc.Sequence, 1)`

Comment: Use `from collections.abc` imports for everything that is there. ["Importing those from typing is deprecated"](https://peps.python.org/pep-0585/#implementation)

Comment: If you use `ruff`, you can write `from typing import...` and get it correctly moved to `collections.abc` and `re` by autofixer without typing that manually, it's quite convenient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, now that the abstractions have settled in a new location, is it fine to use either?

It's better not to do so. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Sequence) specifically says:

> class typing.Sequence(Reversible[T_co], Collection[T_co])
>
> Deprecated alias to collections.abc.Sequence.
>
> Deprecated since version 3.9: collections.abc.Sequence now supports subscripting ([])

If it's deprecated, it may be removed in the next versions of Python. So go with `collections.abc` generic classes.